# Divergence of a vector field discribed by a limit

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

We have a continious and differentiable vector field $ F:\ \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d $, $x \in \mathbb{R}^d $ and $ (A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ a sequence of compact connected sets with smooth boundary of $\mathbb{R}^d$ such, that

$\underline{\text{for all }
\varepsilon>0 \text{ exists } N\in \mathbb{N} \text{ with }} $

$\underline{A_n\subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(x)=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^d:\ ||x-y||<\varepsilon\} \text{ for all } n\geq N }$.

I have to show with that the identity

$ div(F(x))=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\lambda^d(A_n)}\cdot \int\limits_{\partial A_n} \langle F,\mu_n \rangle \ dS $

and $ \mu_n $ is the outer unit normal vector field of $ A_n $.

My attemp: I tried to show this estimation:

For all $ \alpha>0 $ exists $ N_{\alpha}\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ \Bigg|\Bigg| \frac{1}{\lambda^d(A_n)}\cdot \int\limits_{\partial A_n} \langle F,\mu_n \rangle \ dS-div(F(x)) \Bigg|\Bigg|<\alpha $ for all $ n\geq N_{\alpha} $.

But I don't know how I can estimate the inequality useful to proof the claim. Especially I don't see how to use the fact from above (underlined part).

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke Stroke's theorem (or for the classical case that
$n=3$, Gauss's divergence theorem). By Stroke's theorem, the RHS
is the integral of divergence over $A_{n}$. Then by continuity of
div $F$, we have approximation $\mbox{div}F(x)\approx\mbox{div}F(x_{0})$
when $x$ is close to $x_{0}$. Hence $\frac{1}{\mu(A_{n})}\int_{A_{n}}|\mbox{div}F(x)-\mbox{div}F(x_{0})|\,\,dx\rightarrow0$
as the set $A_{n}$ shrinks to the singleton $\{x_{0}\}$.

Comment: As far as now I don't know this theorem so I cannot use it.

Comment: @hallo97 How are you studying vector calculus without knowledge of Stokes's and Gauss's theorem??

Comment: Actually, Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, Green's Theorem, Gauss's Theorem, and Stoke's Theorem are special cases of the general version of Stokes's theorem, which states that the integral of an integrand over the boundary of a region is equal to the integral of its differential form over the region. The classical Green's theorem and the classical Stroke's theorem are for $n=2$, where Green's theorem is actually a special case of the Stroke's ---- the surface is a planar figure. Gauss's theorem works for $n=3$. Dr. Manfredo do Carmo wrote an excellent textbook about differential form.

Comment: I remember that to prove Stroke's theorem, one proves it for a local version (i.e. over a small open neighborhood), then generalize the proof by "partition of unity''.